# Simple application of photo on Android Studio using Android tutorial of Camera

Tags: java, android, image, photo

I want to  create an application  to take a picture. I followed the Camera tutorial, I tried 3 times but unable to make it work.I added a button to take a picture.But the app is not working properly.Please help me out.Here is my code:

```
 // CAMERA VIEW displays the picture in a FrameLayout  
 public class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraView(Context context, Camera camera){
        super(context);

        mCamera = camera;
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
        //get the holder and set this class as the callback, so we can get camera data here
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_NORMAL);

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        try{
            //when the surface is created, we can set the camera to draw images in this surfaceholder
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("ERROR", "Camera error on surfaceCreated " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i2, int i3) {
        //before changing the application orientation, you need to stop the preview, rotate and then start it again
        if(mHolder.getSurface() == null)//check if the surface is ready to receive camera data
            return;

        try{
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
            //this will happen when you are trying the camera if it's not running
        }

        //now, recreate the camera preview
        try{
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("ERROR", "Camera error on surfaceChanged " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        //our app has only one screen, so we'll destroy the camera in the surface
        //if you are unsing with more screens, please move this code your activity
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
    }
}
```

And this is my activity, which takes a picture and save it

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    String TAG = "Main activity";

    private Camera mCamera = null;
    private CameraView mCameraView = null;

    private Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            if (pictureFile == null){
                Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");
                return;
            }

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // app en plein ecran
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // CREATION DU DYNAMIQUE
        final Button menu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMenu);
        menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click
                Intent mainToMenu;
                mainToMenu = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
                startActivity(mainToMenu);
            }
        });

            try {
                mCamera = Camera.open();//you can use open(int) to use different cameras
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("ERROR", "Failed to get camera: " + e.getMessage());
            }

        if(mCamera != null) {
            mCameraView = new CameraView(this, mCamera);//create a SurfaceView to show camera data
            FrameLayout camera_view = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
            camera_view.addView(mCameraView);//add the SurfaceView to the layout
        }

        // quand j appuis sur un btn volume
        final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click

                mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);

            }
        });

    }

    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;

    /** Create a File for saving an image or video */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
        // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "FotoFoto");
        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Post the logcat of your "but it close the application"

Comment: Please check your manifest.Have you given the permission                  uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"  />                 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Yes I got all permission.

Comment: I ll put in few time the logcat ! sorry !

Comment: The error occur when I create the directory !

Comment: File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "FotoFoto");
        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            Log.d("MyCameraApp", "!mediaStorageDir.exists()");
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "!mediaStorageDir.mkdir()");
                return null;
            }
        }